# segmentation fault for vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector, stl, segmentation-fault, const-iterator

why is this code producing a segmentation fault when i try to output the value ?
the segmentation fault is being caused due to the line
**cout << *rit_j;**

```
void chef(vector<int>vec)
{
    int count=0;
    vector<int>::iterator bit = vec.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator eit=vec.end();
    if(*bit != *eit)
    {
        sort(bit,eit);          
        vector<int>::iterator rit_i,rit_j,initial = vec.end();
        --rit_i;--rit_j;--initial;
        cout << *rit_i;

     }
 }
```

Comment: `rit_i` was created with the default constructor, so dereferencing it after doing `--rit_i` is probably not going to do what you want.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen thanks for the reply..but i didn't understand what you said.can you please show the correction that i need to make.

Comment: I don't know what your code is supposed to do, so I can't correct it. But the point is that the `rit_i` variable was initialised with the default constructor. As such, you have an iterator that is not tied to any container. Doing `--rit_i` on such an iterator is undefined.

Comment: @Michael It's not a reverse iterator though, is it? Just a normal iterator at the end of the vector.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen: oops - I guess i read too much into the name `rit_i`.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration:

```
vector<int>::iterator rit_i,rit_j,initial = vec.end();
```

only `initial` is initialized with `vec.end()`. To make it do what I think you expect, you have to write

```
vector<int>::iterator rit_i = vec.end(), rit_j = vec.end(), initial = vec.end();
```

or

```
vector<int>::iterator rit_i,rit_j,initial;
rit_i = rit_j = initial = vec.end();
```

or something to that effect.